# Chartjs Polar Area Chart - Data labels shown don't rotate with startAngle

Tags: chart.js

I am setting the startAngle on my polar chart so the first category starts on the -180 degrees.

But I can't figure out why the data point labels don't correspondingly adjust and rotate.  As a result, they show up incorrectly against the wrong data. As you can see in the image, Question 6 still appears where Question 1 should be. The tooltips on each section do appear correctly.

Note: When I use the datalabels plugin, it does show the label correctly. But I am not using it because it does not wrap the labels and also it cuts off the labels if they become too big. In addition I had responsiveness problems with it.

So please suggest a solution without that plugin if possible.

Thank you very much for helping me out.

```
const mydata = {
  labels: [
    'Question1',
    'Question2',
    'Question3',
    'Question4',
    'Question5',
    'Question6'
  ],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Data labels don't move',
    data: [5, 8, 6, 6, 7, 8],
    backgroundColor: [
      'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
      'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
      'rgb(201, 203, 207)',
      'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      'rgb(201, 203, 207)'
    ]
  }]
};
var myChart = new Chart('mychartId'),
    {
        type: "polarArea",
        data: mydata,

        options:
        {
            responsive: true,
            cutoutPercentage: 20,
            startAngle: -1 * Math.PI,
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            layout: {
                padding: 20
            },
            scale: {
                ticks: {
                    max: 10,
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    min: 1,
                    stepSize: 1,
                    display: false
                },
                angleLines: {
                    display: false
                },
                pointLabels: {
                    display: true

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[sample image showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NFEN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Update to V3, there they do turn with the chart if you adjust the startAngle

```js
var options = {
  type: 'polarArea',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [2, 9, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      r: {
        startAngle: 180,
        ticks: {
          display: false
        },
        pointLabels: {
          display: true
        }
      }
    }

  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
    <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

V3 has some breaking changes over V2, for all of them you can read the [migration guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/v3-migration.html)

Comment: Thank you. I moved to 3.0 and was able to make it work. I can't seem to be able to mark your answer as accepted?

Comment: Would you know how I could rotate the pointLabels just a few degrees so they appear a bit  inside the boundary of the section. Right now they are right on the radial line so a bit confusing to interpret.

Comment: Not possible by default currently afaik, you can use the datalabels plugin. But it also seems like someone is working on implementing this https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/9662